# Calling inner function from parent class function

Tags: python-3.x, function, class, inheritance

I have following setup

```
class Parent:
   def a_outer():
      def a_inner():
         # Do something
         pass
      def b_inner():
         a_inner()
      b_inner()

class Child(Parent)
    def a_outer():
       def b_inner():
          # Change something
          # How can I call the a_inner() method form the parent class??
       b_inner()
```

Within b_inner() function from the inheriting Child class, I how do I access the a_inner() class from the Parent class?

I know this is a little bit confusing, but that's why I'm having this question (and that's also the reason why googling the problem isn't easy; sorry if it is a duplicate)

Comment: You can't. The inner functions are local variables that are forgotten after `a_outer` terminates unless you do something to save them, but if you're doing something to save them then you might as well make them functions of `Parent` instead of defining them locally. Is there a reason they have to be defined inside `a_outer`?

Comment: @ThisIsAQuestion unfortunately the Parent class in my example is from a package so I "cannot" its structure. As a work-around I can simply copy & paste the a_inner() function but that doesn't seem elegant.

Comment: If there is no way at all for you to modify `Parent` then there is no way to solve your problem without copying and pasting `a_inner`. You're right, it's not elegant, but it's your only choice.